# Using ArcGIS styles on QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, style, maps

I would like to use some styles downloaded from the internet in .stylx format within QGIS.
Is there an easy way to do this?
This is the link to the style I would like to use to create maps:

[watercolor maps](https://esri-styles.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=936edb7f57334763a8247d1019a9de51)

Comment: That format comes from ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes I know, but there are paid plugins that allow you to view that styles also on QGIS (like SLYR). I was hoping there could be a free method..

Comment: You could try to recreate it yourself?

Comment: @Erik yes, I think I'll try it on my own..